# Javascript return false in if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

Is it good practice to use "return false;" to basically say do nothing in an if statement? For example:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) {
    return false;
} else {
    //Usual script here
}
```

just wondering if there are any downfalls to this. I can use the if statement without the else but i'm just wanting to get insight on this. I have a plugin that i do not want running on iPad and so I'm wrapping it in the conditional. any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: @user234694 - Please indent lines of code by four spaces, or they will not be formatted as code.

Comment: Better start to mark answers or no one will answer your questions in the future. With your username of random numbers, I am guessing you do not care.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. How do I mark my answers and what does that really mean?

Answer (score 10):

Group 1 will say it is horrible practice since it is hard to follow.

Group 2 will say do it.

Group 3 will say do it, but in 1 line

Group 4 will say do not use the else

Group 5 will say to do not use the return, just use the if around the code you want to run. 
AKA:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) === null) {
    //Usual script here
}
```

Comment: What happens if all 5 groups walk into a bar?

Comment: You'd have one heck of a fight. Bud Spencer style!

Comment: Group 2 will start the fight and loose because they are inefficiently coded and punchGeek() ran a stack overflow.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience only if you were actually looking for the false to be returned.

Comment: In other words, if you want to "do nothing", it's better to actually "do nothing" than to "get out of here and tell them it is false". When "doing nothing" it's also good to make it explicit you're "doing nothing" and not just "forgetting to put code in" with something like `// Do nothing`

Comment: Thanks for the info this certainly helped me gain the insight I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually simplify it further, like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null) return false;
//Usual script here
```

Is it "good practice"...sure, if it works for you and your team.  Jumping out of a function as soon as you have nothing more to do there is a very efficient way to do things, as long as it's easy to understand and maintain for whoever is working on it.

Whether you want `false` specifically depends on the situation, for example if you want to return but not prevent other event handlers from running later, you may want `return true;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info this certainly helped me gain the insight I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

firstly it is very good practise, take this example

```
var window.__page_loaded__;
var Loadpage = function ()
{
    if(window.__page_loaded__ != undefined)
    {
         return; //The page has already laoded
    }

    //Proceed to load the page
}
```

by using the `return;` you doing the same as you would with an `else` statement but without the extra block, and as `Loadpage()` would normally not return any data its perfectly fine to short cut your code.

Comment: Thanks for the info this certainly helped me gain the insight I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should only return a value if a caller is going to do something with that value. If you want to do "nothing" in an if statement, it's a sign that your logic is wrong. Change your statement to this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) == null) {
    //Usual script here
}
```

This way you don't need to "break" out of your function with the return (not a good practice in this scenario).

Comment: I actually prefer to "do nothing" in an `if` statement sometimes to make my code look cleaner (instead of indenting further).

Comment: I don't get that though. Why have `if(condition) {} else { //do something }` when you can have `if(!condition) { //do something }`

Comment: It's never with a single `else`, but more like `if(!condition) {} else if(condition 2) { /* Do something */ } else { /* Do something else */ }` instead of `if(condition) { if(condition 2) { /* Do something */ } else { /* Do something else */ } }`.  It makes my code use less indentation, and I figure a compiler will optimize that however it sees fit.

Comment: I prefer indentation over empty `if` blocks. That speaks of a problem with logic to me :)

Comment: Thanks for the info this certainly helped me gain the insight I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with **snkmchnb**, otherwise just negate the condition. You can negate long expression using these:

```
!(a && b) = !a || !b
!(a || b) = !a && !b
```

And use these several times to get what you want. For example, negating a long expression

```
!( (a && b || c) && (d || e) || f) =
    !((a && b || c) && (d || e)) && !f =
    (!(a && b || c) || !(d || e)) && !f =
    (!(a && b) && !c || !d && !e) && !f =
    ((!a || !b) && !c || !d && !e) && !f
```

This looks ugly now, but negating most times doesn't mean over-complicating. For example negating "<=" results in ">"

So never use !(long_expression) neither:

```
if (long expression)
{
}
else
{
  //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: For reference, these are called the DeMorgan laws (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). And you have a typo in the second law: you want bangs, not pipes.

Comment: @Martinho - bangs? --- oh you mean exclamation marks... `not` s? ==> `!`

Comment: Thanks for the info this certainly helped me gain the insight I'm looking for.