# Is an If branch that does nothing a code smell or good practice?

Tags: conditional-statements, complexity-theory

I've responded to threads here (or at least [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711377/javascript-return-false-in-if-statements/3711410#3711410)) with answers containing code like this, but I'm wondering if it's good or bad form to write a series of `if` branches with one (or more) of the branches doing nothing in them, generally to eliminate checking for `null` in every branch.

An example (C# code):

```
if (str == null) { /* Do nothing */ }
else if (str == "SomeSpecialValue")
{
    // ...
}
else if (str.Length > 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

instead of:

```
if (str != null && str == "SomeSpecialValue")
{
    // ...
}
else if (str != null && str.Length > 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

And, of course, this is just an example, as I tend to use these with larger and more complex classes.  And in most of these cases, a `null` value would indicate to do nothing.

For me, this reduces the complication of my code and makes sense when I see it.  So, is this good or bad form (a code smell, even)?

Comment: I think it's fine if it makes your code more readable and avoids convoluted conditions. Voting to close though, "is this good or bad" is way too subjective.

Comment: The fact that all these checks are needed "just in case" the value is null is a smell in itself, IMHO. By doing this you are hiding bugs.

Comment: @SimonJ: Good point. At least in this case, he ought to throw an exception if a `null` value wasn't expected.

Comment: I'd put '{ /* do nothing--dodge 'else-ifs' */ }' on its own line rather than on the line with the first 'if'.

Comment: This is bad form.  One of the best rules of thumb when coding is "do something once and never again."  This applies both on the large scale (by refactoring common functionality into a single package or class) and on the small scale (by checking a conditional value only once).  The ONLY time you can get away with this is in the XOR scenario (i.e., "if (x == null && y == null) {...} else if (x != null && y != null) {...}") where the logic forces you to do similar checks multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed good to avoid the following, because it *needlessly re-checks one of the conditions* (the fact that the compiler will optimize this away is beside the point--it potentially makes more work for folks trying to read your code):

```
if (str != null && str == "SomeSpecialValue")
{
    // ...
}
else if (str != null && str.Length > 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

But it's also rather bizarre to do what you suggested, below:

```
if (str == null) { /* Do nothing */ }
else if (str == "SomeSpecialValue")
{
    // ...
}
else if (str.Length > 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

I say this is bizarre because it *obfuscates your intent* and *defies the reader's expectations*. If you check for a condition, people expect you to do something if it is satisfied--but you're not. This is because your *intent* is not to actually *process* the null condition, but rather to avoid a null pointer when you check the two conditions you're *actually* interested in. In effect, rather than having two conceptual states to handle, with a sanity provision (non-null input), it reads instead like you have *three* conceptual states to handle. The fact that, *computationally*, you could say there are three such states is beside the point--it's less clear.

The usual case approach in this sort of situation is as Oren A suggested--check for the null, and then check the other conditions within the result block:

```
if (str != null) 
{
 if (str == "SomeSpecialValue")
 {
    // ...
 }
 else if (str.Length > 1)
 {
    // ...
 }
}
```

This is little more than a matter of readability-enhancing style, as opposed to an issue of code smell.

**EDIT**: However, if you're set on the do-nothing condition, I *do* very much like that you included a "do nothing" comment. Otherwise, folks might think you simply forgot to complete the code.

Comment: See edit - I took that (the "[NULL]" string) out because people were getting hung up on that.

Comment: @palswim Okay. But note that wasn't really the main point of my answer. (But at the same time, that code came from somewhere--if it's production code, it's almost certainly a bad thing).

Comment: @user359996: Nope; I didn't want to copy and paste my production code.  I was trying to think of an example on the spot.

Comment: I think it would be fair to say that my brain does have a code smell.  Any time I try to provide an example on this site, someone points out a bad practice in the sample, usually about the example data I've chosen.

Answer (score 21):

I prefer doing it like this-

```
if (str != null) 
{
 if (str == "[NULL]")
 {
    // ...
 }
 else if (str.Length > 1)
 {
    // ...
 }
}
```

I think you can always "reword" an `if` with an empty body into it's negation with a body, and that it looks better and makes more sense.

Comment: I think I have an aversion to too much indentation.  It also saves me a bit of vertical space, and in C#, at least, I'm sure the compiler will handle it well.

Comment: The compiler will handle it well, but IMHO what you're saying has an awkward logic. Why say "if... then do nothing", when you can say "if not.. than do.." About the identation, you can reduce the number of spaces a tab takes, which may help at least a bit.

Comment: Not wanting to properly format code is not a good argument against writing code properly.

Comment: @palswim Anthony Morelli is right. And the indentation is there for the benefit of human readers--not the compiler.

Comment: @user359996: Needing less indentation and vertical space are precisely for the benefit of the readers in this case.

Comment: @palswim Sacrificing readability for horizontal space does not benefit the reader (of course, many would agree what you're doing *doesn't* sacrifice readability--then again, I think I laid down a pretty clear argument that it does, in my answer).

Comment: +1 Doing things the obvious, logical and idiomatic has the best chance of resulting in obvious, logical and idiomatic code.

Answer (score 7):

I would normally put a `return` or something like that in the first `if`:

```
void Foo()
{
  if (str == null) { return; }
  if (str == "SomeSpecialValue")
  {
      // ...
  }
  else if (str.Length > 1)
  {
      // ...
  }
}
```

If you can't do this, because the function does something else after the `if`/`else`, I'd say it's time to refactor, and split the `if`/`else` part out into a separate function, from which you can return early.

Comment: I don't like your indentation style, but this piece of code is the best way, IMHO, to solve the OP's problem.  +1

Comment: @rmeador: Interesting; which indentation style do you like?

Comment: it's not really "my" indentation style, I just tried to stick with the OP's. :)

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case I will return early and it makes code easier to read

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) { return; }
```

I like to put an explicit return statement.

Comment: That only works if the function does nothing else but the `if...else` block.

Comment: This really depends on the semantics of the problem. Very rarely does a null argument mean "do nothing". All too often it means someone has made a mistake, and by silently returning, you're just aggravating the problem. If it's not life-support or the military, fail-fast is often a good idea.

Comment: I completely agree with you and I always do fail fast. I am only replying to this particular question where the use for whatever reason want's to return. This often happens in batch processing where instead of failing you just skip and possibly log what entity was skipped.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** it is a code smell.

One indication is that *you thought to ask this question*.

Another indication is that the code looks incomplete- as if something should belong there. It may be readable sure, but it feels off.

When reading that code, an outsider has to stop for a second and use brainpower to determine if the code is valid/complete/correct/as intended/adjective.

user359996 hit the nail on the head:

> I say this is bizarre because it obfuscates your intent and defies the reader's expectations.

Comment: I don't think that "thinking to ask the question" is necessarily a bad indicator.  Almost none of the code I see, even classic examples of 'good code', looks good to me.  Almost every design pattern looks like a code smell to me, for example.  Almost every example of procedural code makes me "stop for a second and use brainpower" to figure out what was intended.

Comment: @Ken In general "thinking to ask" may not be a sign of a code smell, but in this  situation Id say it was. If no code looks good to you, you either are reading the wrong source, or for some reason just don't like the look of code. (Many) Design patterns are not code smells... exposures of weakness in a language maybe. For the above example- there are better things to get 'stopped on' and expend brain power for than simple code that looks incomplete. I am sorry procedural code causes you trouble.

Comment: instanceofTom: I am sorry a pair of braces with no statements causes you trouble.

Comment: @Ken, insert witty response **here**

Answer (score 2):

Your first example is perfectly readable to me -- doesn't smell at all.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on context.  If putting an empty if statement makes the code more readable, then go for that.

Comment: Yes, but always document it when you do that.  Or, if you're like me and try to make code that doesn't need comments and you're not working in a language that forces everything to be in a class, call a method named Nothing().

Comment: I'm used to working with Python, which has 'pass' included in it (a statement to do nothing).

Answer (score 2):

It's readable, whether it is good or bad depends upon what you are trying to achieve - generally long nested "goes-on-forever" type `if` statements are bad. Don't forget about static string methods baked into the framework: `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` and `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`.

Your `if (str == null) { /* Do nothing */ }` line is unusual, but does have one positive point: it is letting other developers know up front that you are deliberately doing nothing for that case, with your long if/else if structure your intentions could become unclear if you changed it to

```
if (str != null) 
{ 
    /* carry on with the rest of the tests */
}
```